# Cannot drag GridView from the ControlsFX library to my project in SceneBuilder

Tags: javafx, gridview, scenebuilder, controlsfx

Hello I am doing my project in JavaFX and I would like to use GridView from the ControlsFX library. I have successfully imported the library to Scenebuilder, however when I try to drag and drop the GridView onto my project it does not work, I tried dragging it into the Hierarchy section into different Panes also, but it just won't let me do it. Anyone knows, what might be the problem?

I am using SceneBuilder from GluonHQ version 11.0.0, ControlsFX library is in version 8.40.11 - I tried importing one using the "Search repositories" option in SceneBuilder, however that led into the same result.

[image: Image of how it looks when I try to drop it into my project]

Comment: Unfortunately, SceneBuilder does not work with all JFoenix nodes, i had the same issue also with other JFoenix nodes. So you have to define them in code..

Comment: @micpog90 I am new to doing it manually, how would I proceed to do that? I need to add  into the fxml first right? and then define it in my controller.

Comment: You can either define the JFX-Node in the fxml or you can define it in your Controller. Both ways are possible..